# How to randomize or change order of tests with Karma?

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner

I have a set of tests and I suspect they can change the behaviour because of mistakenly shared state.

I'd like to change the order to put the suspicious test on the top or randomize the order completely to rune tests in a different order each time.

How do I make this scenario work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can randomize the test order with Karma, but if your underlying test framework is Jasmine you can force tests using *fdescribe* and *fit*.

I realise you're just trying to identify your issue at the moment, but I'd urge you to try and make the tests as independent as possible, setting up using *beforeEach* to try and eliminate running order dependencies (sorry if that's exactly what you're trying to do).